# Is there a desktop RSS reader that supports G+ integration?

Tags: rss

With the recent neutering of Google reader's sharing capabilities, one of the main draws of using google reader has vanished.

Is there a desktop RSS replacement that can import a list of feeds exported from google reader and import shared items from google plus?

I have written a yahoo pipe to substitute sharing, so I'm interested in readers that perform this task as an internal operation (optimally with oAuth authentication into g+ to access more than simply public shared items.)

Answer (score 1):

Currently Google+ only has an API to read public posts ( https://developers.google.com/+/api/ ), which isn't that helpful. There currently is no RSS feed for a user in Google+. Until one of those two happen you aren't going to find an RSS reader that supports Google+.

Comment: what about http://askubuntu.com/a/118564/45156 ? they suggest liferea.

Comment: Google reader and Google+ are two completely different products.