# RSS reader that syncs with Google Reader?

Tags: software-recommendation, rss

I love Reeder on the Mac and iOS. Is there an RSS reader for Linux/Ubuntu that syncs with Google Reader?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Liferea](http://liferea.sourceforge.net/) has full google reader sync and also good reviews in the software centre.

[image]

**Warning:** It saves your username and password in plain-text (without encryption) which could be a security risk.

[Click here to install.](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/liferea)

Answer (score 2):

Try liferea.

```
sudo apt-get install liferea
```

Advantages:
Read feed contents offline
Full sync for Google Reader and TinyTinyRSS
Google Reader labels support, etc.